# java script - DOM permission

Tags: javascript, events, dom, permissions

How can I call a function in the parent, from iframe (child); when i do it in following way, browser says

```
"Permission denied for <http://localhost> 
to get property Window.func from <http://localhost:8080>.
    [Break On This Error] parent.window.func(); "
```

call in iframe

```
parent.window.func()
```

the function in the parent

```
function func(){
        alert("test")
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, you cannot interact with a frame containing a webpage in a different domain or port.

Comment: can't we change security settings by js?

Comment: No.  Otherwise, a website would make a frame with your bank's homepage and steal your credit card number.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, you are doing a cross-domain request, which breaks the same origin policy.  You can only access other windows if they are from the same domain as the window in question.

`http://localhost` is a different domain to `http://localhost:8080`; the different ports make the request forbidden.